# Azure Function with docker compose unreachable via container port

Tags: docker-compose, azure-functions

Container-to-container calls to an Azure Function App don't work but calls to a Web API from a Function App work (after removing `UseHttpsRedirection`).

I've created a simple solution with ASP.NET Core Web API (.NET 6.0) and an Azure Function App (.NET 6.0) with a HTTP trigger. I've added container orchestration support using Visual Studio 2022.  I want them to be able to call each other using service names such as http://functionapp.

- ✅ Using a REST client, I can call both the Web API and the Function App.
- ✅ The Function App can call the Web API using `http://multicontainerapiandfunction/WeatherForecast` as the URL.
- ❌ The Web API can't call the Function App using `http://functionapp2/api/Function2` as the URL. Error: `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (functionapp2:80)`.
- ✅ The Web API can call the Function App using `http://functionapp2:31744/api/Function2` as the URL.

The launchSettings.json of the Function App contain this:

```json
"Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "httpPort": 31744,
      "useSSL": false
    }
```

The docker-compose and docker-compose.override files have been generated by VS.

The docker-compose.yml is simply:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  multicontainerapiandfunction:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}multicontainerapiandfunction
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MultiContainerApiAndFunction/Dockerfile

  functionapp2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}functionapp2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FunctionApp2/Dockerfile
```

And docker-compose.override.yml is

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  multicontainerapiandfunction:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro

  functionapp2:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

This results in VS showing the Function App's ports like this:
[image: Container view in VS]

I tried changing the `ports` section in docker-compose.override.yml in these two ways:

```yaml
    ports:
      - "31744:80"
```

That results in error during build: "port is already allocated".

```yaml
    ports:
      - "31745:80"
```

That results in the ports being like this:
[image: With port 31745]

- ✅ Port 31744 can be called via a REST client.
- ❌ Port 31745 can't be called via a REST client.
- ❌ Web API can't call the Function App with `http://functionapp2/api/Function2` as the URL.
- ✅ Web API can call with `http://functionapp2:31744/api/Function2`.
- ❌ Web API can't call with `http://functionapp2:31745/api/Function2`

I tried removing the `"httpPort"` from launchSettings.json and then setting `port` sections as above to 31744:

[image: httpPort removed and 31744 configured in the ports section]

- ❌ Port 31744 can't be called via a REST client anymore. `Error: Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)`
- ❌ Web API can't call the Function App with `http://functionapp2/api/Function2` as the URL. `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (functionapp2:80)`
- ❌ Web API can't call with `http://functionapp2:31744/api/Function2`. `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (functionapp2:31744)`

I expected that setting the `ports` to "31744:80" would mean that I can call it with a REST client using port 31744 and the Web API could call it with port 80. However, it seems that it doesn't do anything even though it correctly shows up in VS.
I expected that setting `httpPorts` to 31744 in launchSettings.json just means that I can call 31744 and it's mapped to container port 80. However, it seems that it instead exposes host port 31744 which maps to a container port 31744.

To summarize: Setting the `ports` section doesn't seem to anything. Setting the `httpPorts` works.

Comment: In case if you are still looking for a resolution then please create a support ticket so we can review it. If you don't have the support plan then please let me know.